# spring boot Joda DateTime Serialisation

Tags: datetime, jackson, jodatime, spring-boot, iso8601

I'm trying to serialize Joda DateTime properties as ISO-8601 using Spring Boot v1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Here is my very simple REST Application.

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    class Info{

       private DateTime dateTime;

        public Info(){
            dateTime = new DateTime();
        }
        public DateTime getDateTime() {
           return dateTime;
        }

        public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
           this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/info")
    Info info() {
        return new Info();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
   public Module getModule(){
        return new JodaModule();
   }
}
```

The dateTime is being serialized as a timestamp e.g. `{"dateTime":1415954873412}` 
I've tried adding

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

but that didn't help either. So how do I configure Jackson in Spring Boot to serialize using the ISO-8601 format? 
BTW: I only added the following dependencies to my Gradle build

```
compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.4")
compile("org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.4.2");
```

Answer (score 20):

Since you're using Spring Boot 1.2 you should be able to simply add the following to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

This will give output in the form:

```
{
    "dateTime": "2014-11-18T19:01:38.352Z"
}
```

If you need a custom format you can configure the `JodaModule` directly, for example to drop the time part:

```
@Bean
public JodaModule jacksonJodaModule() {
    JodaModule module = new JodaModule();
    DateTimeFormatterFactory formatterFactory = new DateTimeFormatterFactory();
    formatterFactory.setIso(ISO.DATE);
    module.addSerializer(DateTime.class, new DateTimeSerializer(
        new JacksonJodaFormat(formatterFactory.createDateTimeFormatter()
            .withZoneUTC())));
    return module;
}
```

Comment: I already tried the following each with no success
1. Adding this to the application.properties file   
    spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
2. Creating a bean as follows
    @Bean
    public Module getModule(){
     return new JodaModule();
    }
3. Autowiring the ObjectMapper and setting 
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);    
The only thing that works is to annotate the properties 
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern =  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")

Comment: Works for me. I've pushed my sample to GitHub https://github.com/philwebb/stackoverflow-26926289

Comment: Thanks for that - I got it to work. I was using
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
but it works with:
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
Is this a bug or a feature? :)

Comment: Not that you will also neet the artifact jackson-datatype-joda in your pom

Comment: So glad you posted your example code on GitHub, @PhilWebb . Helped me realize I *had to* use `org.joda.time.DateTime` instead of `java.util.Date` , in the classes I'm trying to serialize ... for this configuration to work. (Notably, Swagger code autogeneration - targetting Spring - uses `java.util.Date` not the joda `DateTime` class). *Update* Actually not positive I've figured this out but hey. Thought I'd share in case it's part of the picture.

Answer (score 8):

With Spring Boot 1.2 you can use a fluent [builder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) for building `ObjectMapper` instance:

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder
              .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
              .build();
}
```

As for `JodaModule`, it will be autoconfigured when `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda` is on classpath.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a `new JodaModule()` to the constructor of your object mapper.

Annotate your Info methods with the ISO pattern

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

or I think you can use this if you're using spring

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: you can also call .setSimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); on your object mapper instead of annotating the classes.

Comment: The only thing that works is if I use the annotation i.e.      
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern =  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
There must be some way of enabling for all DateTime properties. I don't want to have to annotate all the propeties

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but it's probably worth upgrade to 2.4.3, which is the latest version. Also: if `@JsonFormat` override works, but `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` not, I would file a bug against the module -- it should work the way you expect.

Comment: 2.4.3 didn't help. I've tried several approaches but note work. I get the impression that SpringBoot is using a different ObjectMapper instance to the one I'm trying to configure. This looks like a bug to me but I've read in several threads that this should be simply a case of adding the JodaModule

Comment: According to the documentation (§63.3 Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper)
it should be possible to configure application.properties

    spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false

Comment: spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false works for me, with the dependency compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `application.*` in your resources. (I use yamel so it's `.yml` for me, but should be `.properties` by default)

```
spring.jackson.date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

Or whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a joda-date-time-format property (I think this property appeared for the first time in Spring boot 1.3.x versions) that you can set in your application.properties which will work for jackson serialization/deserialization:

From: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

```
spring.jackson.joda-date-time-format= # Joda date time format string. If not configured, "date-format" will be used as a fallback if it is configured with a format string.
```

So if you want to use the ISO format you can set it like this:

```
spring.jackson.joda-date-time-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

You can have different number of 'Z' which changes the way the time zone id or offset hours are shown, from the joda time documentation (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.
```